# building android with cordova

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, gradle

I have an ionic mobile app, i have been building it for IOS and android fine.
But i had to remove android studio from my pc, and then i re-installed it.
And now, I'm not able to build android! I got this error:

> What went wrong: A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
>
> > Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.application']
> >     Minimum supported Gradle version is 4.1. Current version is 3.3. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in
> >     /Users/lamatatwany/Downloads/wesalApp/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties
> >     to gradle-4.1-all.zip

I tried to change the gradle version to the latest and got another error...

Can someone please help me with this.

Cordova requirements output:

> Requirements check results for android: Java JDK: installed 1.8.0
>   Android SDK: installed true Android target: installed
>   android-27,android-26,android-24,android-23 Gradle: installed
>   /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-4.4/bin/gradle
>
> Requirements check results for ios: Apple OS X: installed darwin
>   Xcode: installed 9.2 ios-deploy: not installed  ios-deploy was not
>   found. Please download, build and install version 1.9.0 or greater
>   from https://github.com/phonegap/ios-deploy into your path, or do 'npm
>   install -g ios-deploy' CocoaPods: installed  (node:39026)
>   UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection
>   (rejection id: 1): CordovaError: Some of requirements check failed
>   (node:39026) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise
>   rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are
>   not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit
>   code.

When i update this line in GradleBuilder.js:

> var distributionUrl =
>   process.env['CORDOVA_ANDROID_GRADLE_DISTRIBUTION_URL'] ||
>   'https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-all.zip';

to gradle-4.4-all.zip, igot the following error:

> BUILD FAILED in 1m 13s (node:39180) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning:
>   Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error:
>   /Users/lamatatwany/downloads/wesalapp/platforms/android/gradlew:
>   Command failed with exit code 1 Error output: FAILURE: Build failed
>   with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Could not determine the dependencies of task ':compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
>
>   > Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':debugCompileClasspath'.
>   >     Could not resolve project :CordovaLib.
>   >      Required by:
>   >          project :
>   >     Project : declares a dependency from configuration 'debugCompile' to configuration 'debug' which is not declared in the
>   >     descriptor for project :CordovaLib.

Addin android version 7:

> Installing "cordova-plugin-file-transfer" for android Plugin
>   dependency "cordova-plugin-file@4.3.3" already fetched, using that
>   version. Dependent plugin "cordova-plugin-file" already installed on
>   android. Installing "cordova-plugin-filepath" for android Installing
>   "cordova-plugin-image-picker" for android Installing
>   "cordova-plugin-iroot" for android Failed to install
>   'cordova-plugin-iroot': Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
>   '/Users/lamatatwany/Downloads/wesalapp/platforms/android/AndroidManifest.xml'
>       at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:646:18)
>       at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:551:33)
>       at Object.parseElementtreeSync (/Users/lamatatwany/Downloads/wesalapp/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/cordova-common/src/util/xml-helpers.js:180:27)
>       at new AndroidManifest (/Users/lamatatwany/Downloads/wesalapp/platforms/android/cordova/lib/AndroidManifest.js:29:20)
>       at AndroidProject.getPackageName (/Users/lamatatwany/Downloads/wesalapp/platforms/android/cordova/lib/AndroidProject.js:99:12)
>       at Api.addPlugin (/Users/lamatatwany/Downloads/wesalapp/platforms/android/cordova/Api.js:223:57)
>       at handleInstall (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/install.js:594:10)
>       at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/install.js:357:28
>       at _fulfilled (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/q/q.js:787:54)
>       at self.promiseDispatch.done (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/q/q.js:816:30)

Comment: can you show the output for `cordova requirements` in your project folder?

Comment: "and got another error..." which is..... ?

Comment: @SurajRao just posted it

Comment: hmm.. says gradle version is 4.4 .. how is it picking 3.3? and what is the other error you get?

Comment: @ToYonos just posted it

Comment: @SurajRao just posted it

Comment: what is your cordova-android version?

Comment: @SurajRao   android 6.3.0

Answer (score 0):

You cordova-android version is quite old. The current version is [`7.0.0`](https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/blob/master/RELEASENOTES.md).
This has undergone a number of changes to handle changes in android project structure as well as gradle.

Try:

```
ionic cordova platform update android
```

Else remove the platform and then add:

```
ionic cordova platform add android@latest
```

or

```
ionic cordova platform add android@7.0.0
```

Comment: I alos tried that and got an error T_T just posted it

Comment: depends on the plugin version I think.. havent used that one. you may have to re install the plugins

Comment: how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

When I first built my ionic project in VSC with `ionic Cordova build android`, everything worked. But after generating a signed app bundle with Android Studio, I tried to modify my project, make a new build but got that error :

> Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.application'] Minimum supported Gradle 
>   version is xxx. Current version is xxx. If using the Gradle wrapper, try editing the 
>   distributionUrl in /Users/lamatatwany/Downloads/wesalApp/gradle/wrapper
>   /gradle->wrapper.properties to Gradle-xx.x-all.zip

No answers found to fix it, so I had to rebuild my project from start (with a lot of copy/paste form old project ofc). Now before generating an app bundle with Android Studio, I have to make a backup that I will reuse for futures modifications.